# Building my first orchestration project with ETL pipelines

Tags: python, pandas, airflow, etl, orchestration

I'm an data engineer working in small local company. At this moment we use bunch of Python code which uses Pandas and SQL(for storage) to process work related data. Data is mostly txt, zip archives, xls and csv files stored on our ftp server or on services of our clients(API). This files contain price lists for auto parts. With all due respect to our suppliers, files does not have the same views even across one supplier, so each should be transformed into one view to pass further. And in connection with our growth, I assume that we need to transfer to some *serious* technology to handle more data and do this faster.

I had an idea of transferring our project to some sort of orchestration tool, as Mage.ai or Airflow. Also we would need to make this project unified, so we would be able to connect different sorts of modules related to data analysis and filtration. And main request of my boss - this thing should be able to store input data for some time interval ( for example month for files that update every day(~5 gigs of data) and others for five last files). And this should be done on the same hardware that transforms data in some unified type of storage(close to SQL but less transformed, as close to original as it could be).

Also this project already includes Selenium scripts (which are also should be a part of orchestration) and different sorts of interactions with GCP and other services)

**So, my question is**: What technologies should I take in consideration for orchestration and data warehousing? (Assuming that I and my team worked only on Pandas and Python.)

I would also be very happy to receive advises related to this type of projects if you had some experience with this!

I have tried working with Mage.ai and thought that this project is interesting, but not for me and my team.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use microservices based orchestration as well . If your technology stack is GKE and docker then microservices based orchestration will work fine to handle python code.